# Is there any way to allow several controllers without writing on routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question.

I'm new on rails 4 and ruby 2 and trying to find a way to allow controllers without typing several times on **ROUTES**

I'm tyring to create several actions inside my controller

Here my controller on rails 4:

```
class Managementbla::UserController < ApplicationController
class Managementpoke::UserController < ApplicationController
...
class Managementmultiple::UserController < ApplicationController
```

Here my routes on rails 4:

```
namespace :managementbla do
  resources :user
end

namespace :managementpoke do
  resources :user
end

...

namespace :managementmultiple do
  resources :user
end
```

on rails 2.3 the sintaxis was

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

On rails 4 i found this:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: Because I have a proyect with several controllers and actions, also i have another question... writing all controllers and actions are the correct way of coding,right?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Is there any way to allow several controllers without writing on routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have 500 controllers suggests serious issues with the design of your application. Whatever problem you're solving, I really, really doubt that having 500 similarly-named controllers is the best solution. Do they all perform such vastly different tasks that you need 500 distinct controllers? Forced to guess, I would say that those controllers are all very similar and whatever work they're doing could, and should, be handled by a single controller instead.

If you're determined to continue down the 500-controllers path, though, it's not hard. It seems you may have forgotten that `routes.rb` is just Ruby code. You can solve this the same way you'd solve any problem that requires iterating over a bunch of numbers in Ruby:

```
1.upto(500) do |n|
  namespace :"management#{n}" do
    resources :user
  end
end
```

Don't do this, though. Take a hard look at your 500 controllers. There's got to be a better solution.

Comment: Jordan, I mean 500 not exactly with the same name, i wrote that to do an example but is not the same name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might simplify the application by using either a route parameter or query string parameter.

If you truly need this many routes in your application, you may consider a framework that does routing more efficiently. You might take a look at Roda: http://roda.jeremyevans.net/why.html.

They claim the routing algorithmic efficiency is on order O(log n) where n is the number of routes.